# derivative function in string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, derivative

I want to derivative a function that has given to me in a sting format in MATLAB. for example the input f = 'x^2' is given to me. how can I derivative f to get the answer '2*x' ?
note : I am using MATLAB 2015a.

Comment: Why do you need the input to be a string? Unless you have a list of variables to match inside that string it will be difficult to parse and convert to a symbolic expression.

Comment: @transversalitycondition have you tried just `f=sym('x^2'),df=diff(f)?`

Comment: @AndrasDeak I didn't realize that would work. Thanks for teaching me something!

Comment: @transversalitycondition, no problem:) This is somewhat intuitive to me, however you could also do `symvar('3*x-2*y/2/cos(zz)')` and it would promptly return `{'x'; 'y'; 'zz'}`. Now this is somewhat cool:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Symbolic Math Toolbox, it's very simple:

```
f=sym('x^2');
df=diff(f)
```

Output:

```
>>  diff(sym('x^2'))

    ans =

    2*x
```

This will work as long as your symbolic function has a single non-numeric variable in it.

If you **don't** have symbolic math, then it's a quite different situation...